# Duplicate Delcaration of variable in IF statment VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, if-statement

So I am trying to declare an array within an IF statement that will change how large it is depending on the condition but I keep getting a duplicate error when I go to run the code.

```
    If ZoneComboBox.Value = "Zone 1" Then
        Dim spaces(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As String
        spaces(1, 1) = "ROOM 1"    
        spaces(1, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(2, 1) = "ROOM 2"    
        spaces(2, 2) = "PAUL"
        spaces(3, 1) = "ROOM 3"    
        spaces(3, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(4, 1) = "ROOM 4"    
        spaces(4, 2) = "PAUL"
        spaces(5, 1) = "ROOM 5"    
        spaces(5, 2) = "PAUL"
    End If
    If ZoneComboBox.Value = "Zone 2" Then
        Dim spaces(1 To 6, 1 To 2) As String
        spaces(1, 1) = "SPACE 1"    
        spaces(1, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(2, 1) = "SPACE 2"    
        spaces(2, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(3, 1) = "SPACE 3"    
        spaces(3, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(4, 1) = "SPACE 4"    
        spaces(4, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(5, 1) = "SPACE 5"    
        spaces(5, 2) = "JOE"
        spaces(6, 1) = "SPACE 6"    
        spaces(6, 2) = "JOE"
    End if
```

It was working before I added the 2nd dimension to it to add who owns the room/space but I don't see an error in how I am doing this. Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: scope does not work like this in VBA. your options are to use a different variable name instead of `spaces` in the second `If` block, or to use the `REDIM PRESERVE` statement to reallocate the existing `spaces` array.

Comment: `Dim Spaces() as string` before the `ìf`. And then inside the `then`and `else`, `redim spaces(1 to ..., 1 to ...)` but WITOUT preserve ! The error you are doing is as if you try yo sell me an item and then sell the same item wich is mine to an other person.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is Dim the spaces above the If blocks, and use `Redim spaces(...)` within the IF blocks.

However why do you use separate IF blocks when you compare the same field? Below does what you want in a neater way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SO38818662(Z As String)
    Dim spaces() As String
    Select Case Z
        Case "Zone 1"
            ReDim spaces(1 To 5, 1 To 2)
            spaces(1, 1) = "ROOM 1"
            spaces(1, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(2, 1) = "ROOM 2"
            spaces(2, 2) = "PAUL"
            spaces(3, 1) = "ROOM 3"
            spaces(3, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(4, 1) = "ROOM 4"
            spaces(4, 2) = "PAUL"
            spaces(5, 1) = "ROOM 5"
            spaces(5, 2) = "PAUL"
        Case "Zone 2"
            ReDim spaces(1 To 6, 1 To 2)
            spaces(1, 1) = "SPACE 1"
            spaces(1, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(2, 1) = "SPACE 2"
            spaces(2, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(3, 1) = "SPACE 3"
            spaces(3, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(4, 1) = "SPACE 4"
            spaces(4, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(5, 1) = "SPACE 5"
            spaces(5, 2) = "JOE"
            spaces(6, 1) = "SPACE 6"
            spaces(6, 2) = "JOE"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I might have used LCase or UCase on the value being passed in (to remove problems with mistyped values in a case sensitive comparison) but this is certainly the right idea.